# Debugging paperscript code for paper.js

Tags: javascript, firebug, paperjs

I'm going through a sample code at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/395453/Html-Jigsaw-Puzzle. It's using paper.js which uses text/paperscript for it's script tag.

I would like to find a way to debug this code line by line. Unfortunately VS2013 and Firebug doesn't recognize text/paperscript.

Is it possible to either convert this code to text/javascript or configure a tool to debug paperscript?

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">

    Array.prototype.remove = function (start, end)
    {
        this.splice(start, end);
        return this;
    }

    view.currentScroll = new Point(0, 0);
    var scrollVector = new Point(0, 0);
    var scrollMargin = 32;

    $('#puzzle-image').attr('src', 'content/images/avengers.jpg');

    var imgWidth = $('.puzzle-image').css('width').replace("px", "");
    var imgHeight = $('.puzzle-image').css('height').replace("px", "");

    var config = ({
        zoomScaleOnDrag: 1.125,
        imgName: 'puzzle-image',
        tileWidth: 64,
        tilesPerRow: 10,
        tilesPerColumn: 8,
        imgWidth: imgWidth,
        imgHeight: imgHeight,
        shadowWidth: 120
    });

    var puzzle = new Html5Puzzle(config);
    puzzle.zoom(-.3);
    var path;
    var movePath = false;



    $('.puzzle-image').css('margin', '-' + imgHeight / 2 + 'px 0 0 -' + imgWidth / 2 + 'px');

    function onMouseDown(event)
    {
        puzzle.pickTile();
    }

    function onMouseUp(event)
    {
        puzzle.releaseTile();
    }

    function onMouseMove(event)
    {
        puzzle.mouseMove(event.point, event.delta);

        if (event.point.x < scrollMargin)
        {
            scrollVector = new Point(scrollMargin - event.point.x, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            scrollVector = new Point(0, 0);
        }
    }

    function onMouseDrag(event)
    {
        puzzle.dragTile(event.delta);
    }

    function onKeyUp(event)
    {
        switch (event.key)
        {
            case 'z':
                puzzle.zoom(.1);
                break;
            case 'x':
                puzzle.zoom(-.1);
                break;
        }
    }


    function Html5Puzzle(config)
    {
        instance = this;
        this.currentZoom = 1;
        this.zoomScaleOnDrag = config.zoomScaleOnDrag;
        this.imgName = config.imgName;
        this.shadowWidth = config.shadowWidth;
        this.puzzleImage = new paper.Raster(config.imgName);
        this.puzzleImage.position = view.center;
        this.puzzleImage.visible = false;
        this.tileWidth = config.tileWidth;
        this.tilesPerRow = Math.ceil(config.imgWidth / config.tileWidth);
        this.tilesPerColumn = Math.ceil(config.imgHeight / config.tileWidth);
        this.tileMarginWidth = this.tileWidth * 0.203125;
        this.selectedTile = undefined;
        this.selectedTileIndex = undefined;
        this.selectionGroup = undefined;
        this.shadowScale = 1.5;
        this.tiles = createTiles(this.tilesPerRow, this.tilesPerColumn);

        function createTiles(xTileCount, yTileCount)
        {
            var tiles = new Array();
            var tileRatio = instance.tileWidth / 100.0;

            var shapeArray = getRandomShapes(xTileCount, yTileCount);
            var tileIndexes = new Array();
            for (var y = 0; y < yTileCount; y++)
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < xTileCount; x++)
                {

                    var shape = shapeArray[y * xTileCount + x];

                    var mask = getMask(tileRatio, shape.topTab, shape.rightTab, shape.bottomTab, shape.leftTab, instance.tileWidth);
                    mask.opacity = 0.25;
                    mask.strokeColor = '#fff';

                    var cloneImg = instance.puzzleImage.clone();
                    var img = getTileRaster(
                        cloneImg,
                        new Size(instance.tileWidth, instance.tileWidth),
                        new Point(instance.tileWidth * x, instance.tileWidth * y)
                    );

                    var border = mask.clone();
                    border.strokeColor = '#000';
                    border.strokeWidth = 2;

                    var tile = new Group(mask, border, img, border);
                    tile.clipped = true;
                    tile.opacity = 1;

                    tile.shape = shape;
                    tile.imagePosition = new Point(x, y);

                    tiles.push(tile);
                    tileIndexes.push(tileIndexes.length);
                }
            }

            for (var y = 0; y < yTileCount; y++)
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < xTileCount; x++)
                {

                    var index1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * tileIndexes.length);
                    var index2 = tileIndexes[index1];
                    var tile = tiles[index2];
                    tileIndexes.remove(index1, 1);

                    var position = view.center -
                            new Point(instance.tileWidth, instance.tileWidth / 2) +
                            new Point(instance.tileWidth * (x * 2 + ((y % 2))), instance.tileWidth * y) -
                            new Point(instance.puzzleImage.size.width, instance.puzzleImage.size.height / 2);

                    var cellPosition = new Point(
                        Math.round(position.x / instance.tileWidth) + 1,
                        Math.round(position.y / instance.tileWidth) + 1);

                    tile.position = cellPosition * instance.tileWidth;
                    tile.cellPosition = cellPosition;
                }
            }

            return tiles;
        }

        function getRandomShapes(width, height)
        {
            var shapeArray = new Array();

            for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {

                    var topTab = undefined;
                    var rightTab = undefined;
                    var bottomTab = undefined;
                    var leftTab = undefined;

                    if (y == 0)
                        topTab = 0;

                    if (y == height - 1)
                        bottomTab = 0;

                    if (x == 0)
                        leftTab = 0;

                    if (x == width - 1)
                        rightTab = 0;

                    shapeArray.push(
                        ({
                        topTab: topTab,
                        rightTab: rightTab,
                        bottomTab: bottomTab,
                        leftTab: leftTab
                        })
                    );
                }
            }

            for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {

                    var shape = shapeArray[y * width + x];

                    var shapeRight = (x < width - 1) ?
                        shapeArray[y * width + (x + 1)] :
                        undefined;

                    var shapeBottom = (y < height - 1) ?
                        shapeArray[(y + 1) * width + x] :
                        undefined;

                    shape.rightTab = (x < width - 1) ?
                        getRandomTabValue() :
                        shape.rightTab;

                    if (shapeRight)
                        shapeRight.leftTab = -shape.rightTab;

                    shape.bottomTab = (y < height - 1) ?
                        getRandomTabValue() :
                        shape.bottomTab;

                    if (shapeBottom)
                        shapeBottom.topTab = -shape.bottomTab;
                }
            }
            return shapeArray;
        }

        function getRandomTabValue()
        {
            return Math.pow(-1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
        }

        function getMask(tileRatio, topTab, rightTab, bottomTab, leftTab, tileWidth)
        {

            var curvyCoords = [
                  0, 0, 35, 15, 37, 5,
                  37, 5, 40, 0, 38, -5,
                  38, -5, 20, -20, 50, -20,
                  50, -20, 80, -20, 62, -5,
                  62, -5, 60, 0, 63, 5,
                  63, 5, 65, 15, 100, 0
            ];

            var mask = new Path();
            var tileCenter = view.center;

            var topLeftEdge = new Point(-4, 4);

            mask.moveTo(topLeftEdge);

            //Top
            for (var i = 0; i < curvyCoords.length / 6; i++)
            {
                var p1 = topLeftEdge + new Point(curvyCoords[i * 6 + 0] * tileRatio, topTab * curvyCoords[i * 6 + 1] * tileRatio);
                var p2 = topLeftEdge + new Point(curvyCoords[i * 6 + 2] * tileRatio, topTab * curvyCoords[i * 6 + 3] * tileRatio);
                var p3 = topLeftEdge + new Point(curvyCoords[i * 6 + 4] * tileRatio, topTab * curvyCoords[i * 6 + 5] * tileRatio);

                mask.cubicCurveTo(p1, p2, p3);
            }
            //Right
            var topRightEdge = topLeftEdge + new Point(tileWidth, 0);
            for (var i = 0; i < curvyCoords.length / 6; i++)
            {
                var p1 = topRightEdge + new Point(-rightTab * curvyCoords[i * 6 + 1] * tileRatio, curvyCoords[i * 6 + 0] * tileRatio);
                var p2 = topRightEdge + new Point(-rightTab * curvyCoords[i * 6 + 3] * tileRatio, curvyCoords[i * 6 + 2] * tileRatio);
                var p3 = topRightEdge + new Point(-rightTab * curvyCoords[i * 6 + 5] * tileRatio, curvyCoords[i * 6 + 4] * tileRatio);

                mask.cubicCurveTo(p1, p2, p3);
            }
            //Bottom
            var bottomRightEdge = topRightEdge + new Point(0, tileWidth);
            for (var i = 0; i < curvyCoords.length / 6; i++)
            {
                var p1 = bottomRightEdge - new Point(curvyCoords[i * 6 + 0] * tileRatio, bottomTab * curvyCoords[i * 6 + 1] * tileRatio);
                var p2 = bottomRightEdge - new Point(curvyCoords[i * 6 + 2] * tileRatio, bottomTab * curvyCoords[i * 6 + 3] * tileRatio);
                var p3 = bottomRightEdge - new Point(curvyCoords[i * 6 + 4] * tileRatio, bottomTab * curvyCoords[i * 6 + 5] * tileRatio);

                mask.cubicCurveTo(p1, p2, p3);
            }
            //Left
            var bottomLeftEdge = bottomRightEdge - new Point(tileWidth, 0);
            for (var i = 0; i < curvyCoords.length / 6; i++)
            {
                var p1 = bottomLeftEdge - new Point(-leftTab * curvyCoords[i * 6 + 1] * tileRatio, curvyCoords[i * 6 + 0] * tileRatio);
                var p2 = bottomLeftEdge - new Point(-leftTab * curvyCoords[i * 6 + 3] * tileRatio, curvyCoords[i * 6 + 2] * tileRatio);
                var p3 = bottomLeftEdge - new Point(-leftTab * curvyCoords[i * 6 + 5] * tileRatio, curvyCoords[i * 6 + 4] * tileRatio);

                mask.cubicCurveTo(p1, p2, p3);
            }

            return mask;
        }

        var hitOptions = {
            segments: true,
            stroke: true,
            fill: true,
            tolerance: 5
        };

        function getTileRaster(sourceRaster, size, offset)
        {
            var targetRaster = new Raster('empty');
            var tileWithMarginWidth = size.width + instance.tileMarginWidth * 2;
            var data = sourceRaster.getData(new Rectangle(
                offset.x - instance.tileMarginWidth,
                offset.y - instance.tileMarginWidth,
                tileWithMarginWidth,
                tileWithMarginWidth));
            targetRaster.setData(data, new Point(0, 0))
            targetRaster.position = new Point(28, 36);
            return targetRaster;
        }

        this.pickTile = function ()
        {
            if (instance.selectedTile)
            {
                if (!instance.selectedTile.lastScale)
                {
                    instance.selectedTile.lastScale = instance.zoomScaleOnDrag;
                    instance.selectedTile.scale(instance.selectedTile.lastScale);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (instance.selectedTile.lastScale > 1)
                    {
                        instance.releaseTile();
                        return;
                    }
                }

                instance.selectedTile.cellPosition = undefined;

                instance.selectionGroup = new Group(instance.selectedTile);

                var pos = new Point(instance.selectedTile.position.x, instance.selectedTile.position.y);
                instance.selectedTile.position = new Point(0, 0);

                instance.selectionGroup.position = pos;
            }
        }

        this.releaseTile = function ()
        {
            if (instance.selectedTile)
            {

                var cellPosition = new Point(
                    Math.round(instance.selectionGroup.position.x / instance.tileWidth),
                    Math.round(instance.selectionGroup.position.y / instance.tileWidth));

                var roundPosition = cellPosition * instance.tileWidth;

                var hasConflict = false;

                var alreadyPlacedTile = getTileAtCellPosition(cellPosition);

                hasConflict = alreadyPlacedTile;

                var topTile = getTileAtCellPosition(cellPosition + new Point(0, -1));
                var rightTile = getTileAtCellPosition(cellPosition + new Point(1, 0));
                var bottomTile = getTileAtCellPosition(cellPosition + new Point(0, 1));
                var leftTile = getTileAtCellPosition(cellPosition + new Point(-1, 0));

                if (topTile)
                {
                    hasConflict = hasConflict || !(topTile.shape.bottomTab + instance.selectedTile.shape.topTab == 0);
                }

                if (bottomTile)
                {
                    hasConflict = hasConflict || !(bottomTile.shape.topTab + instance.selectedTile.shape.bottomTab == 0);
                }

                if (rightTile)
                {
                    hasConflict = hasConflict || !(rightTile.shape.leftTab + instance.selectedTile.shape.rightTab == 0);
                }

                if (leftTile)
                {
                    hasConflict = hasConflict || !(leftTile.shape.rightTab + instance.selectedTile.shape.leftTab == 0);
                }

                if (!hasConflict)
                {

                    if (instance.selectedTile.lastScale)
                    {
                        instance.selectedTile.scale(1 / instance.selectedTile.lastScale);
                        instance.selectedTile.lastScale = undefined;
                    }

                    instance.selectionGroup.remove();
                    var tile = instance.tiles[instance.selectedTileIndex];
                    tile.position = roundPosition;
                    tile.cellPosition = cellPosition;
                    instance.selectionGroup.remove();
                    instance.selectedTile =
                    instance.selectionGroup = null;
                    project.activeLayer.addChild(tile);

                    var errors = checkTiles();
                    if (errors == 0)
                    {
                        alert('Congratulations!!!');
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function getTileAtCellPosition(point)
        {
            var width = instance.tilesPerRow;
            var height = instance.tilesPerColumn;
            var tile = undefined;
            for (var i = 0; i < instance.tiles.length; i++)
            {
                if (instance.tiles[i].cellPosition == point)
                {
                    tile = instance.tiles[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            return tile;
        }

        this.dragTile = function (delta)
        {
            if (instance.selectedTile)
            {
                instance.selectionGroup.position += delta;
                instance.selectedTile.opacity = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                var currentScroll = view.currentScroll - delta * instance.currentZoom;
                view.scrollBy(currentScroll);
                view.currentScroll = currentScroll;
            }
        }

        this.mouseMove = function (point, delta)
        {
            if (!instance.selectionGroup)
            {
                project.activeLayer.selected = false;
                if (delta.x < 8 && delta.y < 8)
                {
                    var tolerance = instance.tileWidth * .5;
                    var hit = false;
                    for (var index = 0; index < instance.tiles.length; index++)
                    {
                        var tile = instance.tiles[index];
                        var row = parseInt(index / config.tilesPerRow);
                        var col = index % config.tilesPerRow;

                        var tileCenter = tile.position;

                        var deltaPoint = tileCenter - point;
                        hit = (deltaPoint.x * deltaPoint.x +
                                deltaPoint.y * deltaPoint.y) < tolerance * tolerance;

                        if (hit)
                        {
                            instance.selectedTile = tile;
                            instance.selectedTileIndex = index;
                            tile.opacity = .5;
                            project.activeLayer.addChild(tile);
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tile.opacity = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!hit)
                        instance.selectedTile = null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                instance.dragTile(delta);
            }
        }

        this.zoom = function (zoomDelta)
        {
            var newZoom = instance.currentZoom + zoomDelta;
            if (newZoom >= 0.3 && newZoom <= 1)
            {
                view.zoom =
                instance.currentZoom = newZoom;
            }
        }

        function checkTiles()
        {
            var errors = 0;
            var firstTile = instance.tiles[0];
            var firstCellPosition = firstTile.cellPosition;

            for (var y = 0; y < instance.tilesPerColumn; y++)
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < instance.tilesPerRow; x++)
                {
                    var index = y * instance.tilesPerRow + x;
                    var cellPosition = instance.tiles[index].cellPosition;

                    if (cellPosition != firstCellPosition + new Point(x, y))
                    {
                        errors++;
                    }
                }
            }

            return errors;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place a `debugger;` statement on any given line in your PaperScript code, which will trigger the debugger to stop in the translated JavaScript code, if it the developer console is open. After that you can step through the code. Line numbers remain the same, comments are preserved, and code should largely look similar, so it should be a fairly comfortable way to debug the code.

Comment: Is there another way? This way of debugging works terrible for me.

Comment: it does not work if there is a syntax error which prevents compilation of the script: even "debugger;" in first line is not executed.